# Setting ABI Target with Android CMake Builds

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

Using `Application.mk`, it looks like the ABI targets can be selected with the option `APP_ABI`:

`APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64,mips`

I can't seem to find any such options for CMake builds. The file `CMakeLists.txt` seems to be called with the `ANDROID_ABI` option passed in, but I can't find any corresponding configuration options in the gradle plugin.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [**abiFilters**](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.html):

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    ndk {
        abiFilters "x86"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually it looks like the ndk section needs to be inside defaultConfig, such as android { defaultConfig { ndk { abiFilters "..." }}}

Comment: Application.mk allows to set project-wide settings like APP_STL, APP_CFLAGS. can we configure such properties in a file for cmake also instead of passing in command-line arguments?

Comment: @VivekMangal yes you can, to some extent. Still, command-line arguments from build.gradle are the best way.

Comment: How? Actually In Application.mk we can write scripts,conditions etc . So I wanted a separate file for app parameters and gradle should refer to that file

Comment: @VivekMangal you can use `Application.mk` when you build from gradle. The catch is that whatever arguments gradle chooses to overwrite, it will. `APP_ABI` is maybe the most prominent case.

Comment: Is there a way to specify Application.mk file to cmake. NDK_APPLICATION_MK doesn't seem to be working. Also nothing mentioned on android docs about this.

Comment: @VivekMangal **ndkBuild** and **CMake** are different competing engines that use NDK to compile and link the native code for your Android application. They come each with completely different philosophy. Mixing the two is not supported. **CMake** language is by no means less rich and flexible than *gnumake* that you use to write your **Application.mk**.